# How to generate a table in Struts 2, using the data from the form

Tags: struts2

This is my form from the JSP file:

```
<s:form action="register">
  <s:textfield name="personBean.firstName" label="Ime" />
  <s:textfield  name="personBean.lastName" label="Prezime" />
  <s:textfield name="personBean.email"  label ="E-mail"/>  
  <s:textfield name="personBean.age"  label="Godine"  />

  <s:submit/>
</s:form>
```

How do I generate a table from the data inserted into the form's textfields by clicking on the submit button?

Comment: What do you mean by generating a table?

Comment: First you need to generate a table then data to submit.

Comment: do you understand actually what are you talking about ,please put some efforts while asking?

Comment: By generating I mean that when I click on the submit button, all data from the form is displayed in a table. But I guess I have to create a table as well?

Comment: @user2440009 Do you need to store that data in a database? Because if you only want to display the information once and "lose it" you can use JavaScript or jQuery, you don't need struts.